# Get user who has transaction in last 7 days, and only one transaction in 30 days

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like below, today is 2021-05-25.

| UserId | TransactionDate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-05-21 |
| 1 | 2021-05-12 |
| 4 | 2021-05-25 |
| 1 | 2021-04-03 |
| 3 | 2021-05-15 |
| 3 | 2021-04-02 |
| 4 | 2021-03-25 |

I want the output is 4.

Since 1 has transaction within 7 days, but 2 transactions within 30days.
3 don't have any transaction within 7 days.
Only 4 has transaction within 7 days, and that's the only transaction within 30 days.

I can only filtered by the first condition using

```
WHERE t.TransactionDate > to_date('2021-05-17')
GROUP BY 1
```

Can anyone help how to apply both condition?

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation with `having`:

```
select userid
from t
where transactiondate >= curdate() - interval 30 day
group by userid
having count(*) = 1 and
       max(transactiondate) >= curdate() - interval 7 day;
```

If you want the transaction detail, it is a little more complciated:

```
select t.*
from transactions t
where t.transactiondate >= curdate() - interval 7 day and
      not exists (select 1
                  from transactions t2
                  where t2.userid = t.userid and
                        t2.transactiondate >= curdate() - interval 30 day and
                        t2.transactiondate <> t.transactiondate
                 );
```

Comment: The filter by `interval 30` is just in place to get a piece of data from the table. Because of it's just a performance improvement,I would change it for 7, because records older than 7 days will be rejected by the `having` clause.

Comment: Thanks! having max(transactionDate > today-7) works!

Comment: @JaimeDrq . . . Not exactly.  The code has to guarantee that there is a transaction in the previous seven days, but not in the 23 days before that.